# During Deploy data collection rule getting error

Tags: azure

##[error]Exception type: ErrorResponseCommonV2Exception, Message: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseCommonV2Exception: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.DataCollectionRulesOperations.CreateWithHttpMessagesAsync(String resourceGroupName, String dataCollectionRuleName, DataCollectionRuleResource body, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.DataCollectionRulesOperationsExtensions.CreateAsync(IDataCollectionRulesOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String dataCollectionRuleName, DataCollectionRuleResource body, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.DataCollectionRulesOperationsExtensions.Create(IDataCollectionRulesOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String dataCollectionRuleName, DataCollectionRuleResource body)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.DataCollectionRules.NewAzureRmDataCollectionRuleCommand.ProcessRecordInternalByFile()
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.DataCollectionRules.NewAzureRmDataCollectionRuleCommand.ProcessRecordInternal()
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.MonitorCmdletBase.ExecuteCmdlet(), Code: Null, Status code:Null, Reason phrase: Null
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

I need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ErrorResponseCommonV2Exception:
> **Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'**

I faced a `BadRequest` error while trying to deploy a `DCR` using `PowerShell` because of an incorrect `JSON` file.

[image]

To resolve the issue, check your `DCR.json` file. In my case, the `JSON` file was incorrect with `samplingFrequencyInSeconds": 10`, but it started working after changing it to `samplingFrequencyInSeconds": 60`."

**DCR.json**

```json
     {
     "properties": {
        "dataSources": {
          "performanceCounters": [
            {
              "streams": [
                "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"
              ],
              "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
              "samplingFrequencyInSeconds": 60,
              "counterSpecifiers": [
                "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Processor Time"
              ],
              "name": "perfCounter01"
            }
          ]
        },
        "destinations": {
          "azureMonitorMetrics": {
            "name": "azureMonitorMetrics-default"
          }
        },
        "dataFlows": [
          {
            "streams": [
              "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"
            ],
            "destinations": [
              "azureMonitorMetrics-default"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

```
Install-Module -Name "Az.Monitor"
New-AzDataCollectionRule -ResourceGroupName "Resource-Group-Name" -Location "eastus" -RuleName "DCRule01" -RuleFile "./dcrrule.json" -Description "Data Collection Rule"
```

**Output:**

After running the above command, `DCR` was successfully created as shown below.

[image]

Reference:  [Azure Powershell DCR creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/new-azdatacollectionrule?view=azps-10.3.0) @ [Azure CLI data-collection rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/data-collection/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-data-collection-rule-create%28monitor-control-service%29)